# Preciso criar um intent dentro de outro intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Criei um APP Widget com 3 botões.

Neste trecho de código atribui as funções dos botões:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_widget);

        Intent intent_busca = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.br"));
        PendingIntent pending_busca = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent_busca, 0);

        Intent intent_exemplo = new Intent(context, ExemploActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pending_exemplo = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent_exemplo, 0);

        Intent intent_stack = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://pt.stackoverflow.com"));
        PendingIntent pending_stack = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent_stack, 0);


        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_busca_btn, pending_busca);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_exemplo_btn, exemplo_scan);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_stack_btn, pending_stack);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```

Porém, queria fazer uma alteração nos meus `intents`. Antes de cada ação dessas eu queria primeiro direcionar meu usuário para a `MainActivity`.

> Click > MainActivity > Funcionalidade clicada.

Answer (score 0):

Sete um Action ou Extra diferente em cada um dos intents e depois na MainActivity recupere o mesmo e faça a ação necessária com base no que foi capturado.